# What Google Maps API version is used by default?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What version of the Google Maps API is used if you don't specify a version number?  The latest release version perhaps?  The [documentation about versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) doesn't say.

The documentation does recommend that production apps specify a minor version number.  But it also says "all API changes will be backwards-compatible," so is there any reason I should specify a version number if I'm not using any experimental features?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

English is not my first language, so I might be reading this part wrong (from the versioning doc you linked)

> You can indicate which version of the API to load within your application by specifying it using the v parameter ... The nightly (development) version, specified with v=3 or by omitting the v parameter.

Further down, there's a mention of 3.9 being nightly.

> **Documentation of Versions**
>
> Version 3.9 Reference (Nightly)

So, sounds like leaving out the v (which I do) will load the nightly, version 3.9.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

About part two of your question: I can think of a very good reason to specify a version:

**Consistency, predictability, reliability**

You might want to keep the same look-and-feel while working on a update for the latest release of the Maps API. For example, the labels or map controls may move around.

On the other hand, it's good to keep track of the latest versions, too. By lagging too far behind your application might stop working when it becomes unsupported.

I'm sure there are better reasons. I'm not a professional Maps developer.

Comment: Aha!  I didn't see that little "or by omitting the v parameter" phrase tucked into the bullet point about the nightly version.  I think they could have made that more clear by mentioning that at the beginning of the documentation section about versions.  But thanks for pointing that out, that answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

I've been building extensive Google Maps based applications and according to my experience it's better to specify API version for a long term projects. For example an issue I was facing recently:
The system was built and tested along with [v3.6](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) but Google released an [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference)

Which is loaded by default but from the other hand not recommended for business or professional development.

Therefore to avoid some malfunction that appeared suddenly I had to specify API version:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.16" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then after that everything came back to normal. You may quickly consult API version by typing in the browser console `google.maps.version`.

I hope someone may find it useful.