# Version specific paths to Google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using this path to load Google maps

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

In some cases I need to be able to load an older version of the API but are unable to find the links.

Anyone who know where to find?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)

The following bootstrap request illustrates how to request a specific version of the Maps Javascript API:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&sensor=true_or_false

Currently the available versions are:
Version 3.10 Reference (Release)
Version 3.11 Reference (Experimental)
Version 3.9 Reference (Frozen)
Versions 3.0 - 3.8 have been retired.

When a version is retired it is no longer available, you are served the "Frozen" version.

Comment: Does this actually work? I'm requesting `v=3.15` and when checking the version in the console `google.maps.version` returns `3.16.2`

Comment: It does for me, although I usually request v=3 (the "release" version).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that not specifying a version and using `v=3` will get you the nightly build. I can't find the docs link now, but this is the gist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758840/what-google-maps-api-version-is-used-by-default?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: v=3.exp gets you the "experimental version" (which I don't think changes "nightly" but certainly could).  See [Versioning in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?csw=1#Versioning)